# How to use PHPUnit administrative connection to query DB?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Using the PHPUnit administrative connection to the database would avoid "polluting" any logging or other things going on inside of our app code with an SQL command that's only being used to implement the test.

I'd like to use $this->getConnection() to grab the administrative PHPUnit connection to the database rather than call our SystemDB::query() function directly, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Mock `SystemDB` class and/or other classes. Also you consider to refactor your code when it makes so much trouble to test it as testability is characteristic for good code

Comment: I'm interning at the company doing unit tests, so I currently don't have access to refactor the application code

Comment: wow!! tell me where can I get such a job! (mostly I've done is unpayed at night)

Comment: The company's name is Aladtec (based out of Wisconsin), and this is how I figured out to do it.

$result = $this->getConnection()->getConnection();
  $query = $result->query( $sql );
  $array = $query->fetchAll();

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$result = $this->getConnection()->getConnection();
$query = $result->query( $sql );
$my_array = $query->fetchAll();
```

where $sql is the query and getConnection() is implemented according to the main phpUnit manual page http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html